# How to create a heat map in R?

Tags: r, heatmap

I am doing a multiple part project. To begin with I had a data set which provided the deposits per district over the years. After scrubbing the data set, I was able to create a data frame, which provides the growth of deposits by district.  I have growth of deposits by 3 different kinds of institutions - foreign banks, public banks and private banks in 3 different data frames as the # of rows differs in each frame. I have been asked to create 3 maps (heat maps) with deposit growth against each of the kind of banks.

My data frame looks like the attached picture.

I want to make a heat map for the growth column. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTPIT.png)

Thanks.

Comment: could you give a small sample of your data set ? There are two kind of heatmap : a colored matrix and a real map with maps on hit. For the first case, I recommand to use ggplot with geom_tile() : http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Show example data (by `dput()` or by giving the definition of a dataframe) and what you tried (your code)!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I provide some spam by this answer, so delete it without hasitation.

I'll show you how I make some heatmaps in R:
Fake data:

```
         Gene   Patient_A Patient_B Patient_C Patient_D
         BRCA1        52        46       124      148
         TP53         512       487      112      121
         FOX3D        841       658      321      364
         MAPK1        895       541      198      254
         RASA1        785       554      125      69
         ADAM18       12        65       85       121

hmcols <- rev(redgreen(2750))
heatmap.2(hm_mx, scale="row", key=TRUE, lhei=c(2,5), symkey="FALSE", density.info="none", trace="none", cexRow=1.1, cexCol=1.1, col=hmcols, dendrogram = "none")
```

[image]

In case of `read.table` you propably will have to convert data frame to matrix and put first column as a row names to avoid errors from R:

```
hm <- read.table("hm1.txt", sep = '\t', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
row.names(hm) <- hm$Gene
hm_mx <- data.matrix(hm)
hm_mx <- hm_mx[,-c(1)]
```